# Local WAMP environment to mimic live sites

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

I have multiple sites that sit off the www folder under a windows wamp install.

What I'd like to be able to do is specify relative paths for all links within each page / js / css throughout each site. So rather than having to use

`http://localhost/sitea/_assets/images/image1.jpg,` I could use `/_assets/images/image1.jpg` etc.

I need to setup a rewrite rule for this in .htaccess - can anyone recommend a rule that will achieve this?

Comment: Why don’t you set up a [virtual host named “sitea.local”](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gumbo - thanks for the heads up. Worked perfectly.  I used [Configuring Multiple Domains within WAMP for Local Development](http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/configuring-multiple-domains-within-wamp-for-local-development/) in the end.